# Share files and folders between Mac, Windows and Linux

Tags: files, ftp, file-sharing

I've read a lot about this but I want this a little bit different. The articles about FTP and folder sharing all needs a specific software at both end hosts like SAMBA. But I want to connect the server using the address and a password without installing additional software, so me and my friends could share some documents with ease. I want to host an FTP server on my Arch Linux and copy files in there from other OSes wirelessly(MAC/Windows). The ones connecting the server would need to provide passwords to access the FTP server but wouldn't need any additional software. We're all on the same WiFi. Is it possible?

Comment: If you pick an FTP server, they will need an FTP client. Same goes for `samba` and pretty much every other network file sharing system. If upload is not required, you can use a HTTP server to serve any directory

Comment: If they were all Linux machines, setting up SSH would allow you to use SFTP on the command line. I know nothing about the capabilities of Windows - but it claims to support Linux???

Comment: Maybe it is an overkill, but I would recommend to install some opensource collaboration server (https://www.goodfirms.co/blog/best-free-open-source-collaboration-software). You can share documents, and much more. In that way, clients only need a browser, and possibly some apps to edit documents, but I guess document manipulation apps are not a problem. At least some of the collaboration portals can be installed as docker images, which makes installation pretty simple.

Comment: @Panki We can be on the same WiFi network. I just want something that my Arch Linux will host on certain ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx and Windows and Mac users can just join by connecting to certain ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx. I've seen my SAD teacher from school do that to share some resources. And I could just connect to that ftp from my Mac and it worked just fine.